# Почему когда ставлю tag в git то он как то отделяется?

Tags: git, git-tag

Вот работаю на ветке, делаю версию и ставлю таг и он как то отделяется в сторону

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

version 1.10, 1.11

почему так?

хотя прошлый комит 1.09 нормально выглядит

Comment: Не похоже на git :-)

Comment: Тэг похож по своей сущности на бренч. Можно даже сделать checkout на тэг.

Comment: @ilyaplot бранч как бы тоже не должен создавать отдельного коммита

Comment: Может это только инструмент ваш так отображает? Что в git log к примеру?

Comment: @PavelMayorov UI другой , но это git

Comment: @ilyaplot так checkout можно сделать на любой кормит по его id так они же нормально отображаются

Comment: @Monk нет , вот я обновил картинку в вопросе, там видно , что первый таг нормально стал

Comment: Выложите что-нибудь с консольным отображением. Мне лично инструмент незнаком и непонятно, что это может быть.

Comment: Сравните содержимое файлов `.git/refs/heads/master` и `.git/refs/tags/1.11`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выглядит так, будто у вас есть три разных коммита с одинаковым сообщением `updated gradle version code`. Один из них помечен тегом `1.10`, но не принадлежит никакой ветке. Другой принадлежит ветке `master ⌖`, а третий — ветке `master`  (точнее символов не нашёл). Среди этих двух веток `master` какая-то ваша локальная (просто `master`), а какая-то на сервере (`origin/master`), но иконки этого различия не передают.

Почему такое могло произойти:

- Вы дважды переписали один коммит с помощью команды `git commit --amend`.
- Вы трижды делали коммит с одинаковым названием, а в промежутках откатывались с помощью `git reset --soft HEAD^`.
- Инструмент для просмотра истории — глючный, а на самом деле там один коммит.

Что с этим делать?

- Пользуйтесь консолью. Не пользуйтесь (глючными) GUI-инструментами.
- Историю смотрите с помощью `git log`. Держите удобный alias:

  ```
  git config --global alias.lg "log --color --graph --abbrev-commit --all \
  --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow ul)%d%Creset %s \
  %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'"
  ```

  Потом просто:

  ```
  git lg
  ```
- Коммиты переберите и найдите единственный верный. Как на него переставить тег и `origin/master` – отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Так себе алиас, ничего не понятно же) Вот мой: `hist = log --pretty=format:'%C(auto)%h %ad | %s%d <%an>' --graph --all --date=short`

Comment: Хотя, если перенос на вторую строку не был запланирован, то норм))

Comment: я так и пользуюсь консолью, этот UI использую чтоб наглядно видеть что где...

Comment: Я использовал элиас который вы предложили и действительно видно, что это не глюк UI , так и есть это лишние коммиты. Вопрос, из возможных вариантов почему такое могло произойти подходит только `--amend` я часто пользуюсь этой командой, но хотел спросить, что значит "вы дважды переписали один коммит"? Насколько я знаю эта команда просто добавляет изменения в предыдущий коммит, но почему она создала новые?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko отличная тема для нового вопроса. Я вам подробно отвечу.

Comment: Вот он вопрос насчет создания коммита https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/662457/Почему-git-commit-amend-создает-новый-коммит

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте добавить любой коммит в master.

Если проблема уйдет, то виной тому ваша программа для отображения истории. Вероятно, она не умеет отображать одновременно две ссылки на один коммит. Кстати, что за программа?

Если нет - значит у вас в истории проблема, есть два похожих коммита.

Comment: эта поделка называется https://www.gitkraken.com/ . Я ее пропобовал - абсолютно не возможно использовать.

Comment: @KoVadim а какая вам по душе?)

Comment: консоль. она правильная и предсказуемая. И даже, кроссплатформенная! (git bash для винды, в линукс просто git в консоле).

Comment: @KoVadim я так и пользуюсь консолью, этот UI использую чтоб наглядно видеть что где...