# Почему `git commit --amend` создает новый коммит?

Tags: git

Исходя из этого лога видно, что есть лишние кометы

```
* 100ef3f - (HEAD -> master) ss (4 hours ago) 
* 6392bff - version 1.11 (27 hours ago) 
| * c740677 - (tag: 1.11) version 1.11 (2 days ago) 
|/  
* bbc79f8 - test one (2 days ago) 
* 2443876 - -updated gradle version **//** (4 days ago) 
| * 4ef2ee2 - (tag: 1.10) -updated gradle version **//** (4 days ago) <Shahar bm>
|/  
| * 2562070 - (origin/master, origin/HEAD) -updated gradle version **//**. (8 days ago)
|/  
* 8e2dad6 - -merge. -added ws for **//** (9 days ago)
* 1820027 - final commit (9 days ago) 
* 8b35461 - test commit (9 days ago) 
* 0d69468 - -changes in **//** . (2 months ago) 
* 1f12302 - (tag: 1.09) Version 1.09 (3 months ago) 
* 51cb421 - -added **//**
* ad0ecef - -git init. (5 months ago)
```

Так же изображение только из UI

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот есть предположение благодаря @NickVolynkin , что эти коммиты создаются в следствии использования команды `git commit --amend`

Но насколько я понимаю эта команда должна прибавить текущие изменения в прошлый коммит

Почему создается новый?

Comment: Если хотите глубже разобраться в вопросе, есть очень неплохая стать про "кишки" гита https://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/git_guts.txt.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Потому что коммит неизменяем.** Его идентификатор, хэш, зависит от его содержимого. Меняете содержимое — меняется хэш, получается коммит **с другим идентификатором**, но от того же основания, что и текущий коммит.

Жаловаться на это это примерно как жаловаться на то, что если к 5 прибавить ещё единичку, получится совсем другое число `:)`

`git commit --amend` "забывает" про текущий коммит, берёт тот же коммит на котором был основан старый*, делает поверх него* новый коммит, учитывая содержимое индекса** и переносит ветку на получившийся результат. Изменения существующих коммитов реально не происходит.

На самом деле это **хорошо**. Это избавляет от сюрпризов из серии "где-то что-то неожиданно изменилось". А для системы контроля версий это хорошая черта.

Поэтому существует практика:

> #### никогда не делать `commit --amend` на опубликованных коммитах***

...а то сами видите, к чему это приводит.

---

*Впрочем, система не идеальна, и [недавние новости про взлом SHA-1](https://shattered.io/), который используется внутри Git, было посеяли сомнения, не даёт ли это возможности подделывать хэш каким-нибудь левым изменениям так, чтобы Git ничего не заподозрил.*

*Беспокоиться об этом пока рано, всем кроме разве что самых крупных ИТ-гигантов. На практике используется ещё и длина данных, что на порядок затрудняет подбор коллизии. А это и без того непросто, практически нереально: на известный случай взлома ушло около 6500 ЦПУ-лет. Нужна крайне серьёзная причина, чтобы выделить такое количество ресурсов на каждую подобную операцию.*

---

* или несколько коммитов, если заменяется коммит слияния

** а там, если что, все отслеживаемые файлы, а не только изменённые, поэтому если ветка внезапно начинает указывать на другой коммит, сравнение с состоянием в индексе (и, как следствие, вычисление изменений для коммитов) по-прежнему работает правильно

*** с кучей "если": скажем, **если** это не лично ваша ветка, на которую никто кроме вас рассчитывать не собирается, а если собирается, то сам виноват; хороший пример это фича-ветки их разнообразных Git*-flow.

Comment: Хорошо пишете, увлекательно даже. )

Comment: Не совсем понял, значит представим ситуацию я сделал коммит "version1" и тут вспомнил, что мне нужно немного там что то сделать(поменять пару строк кода) , я поменял и вот теперь мне все нравится. Что я делаю я пишу `git add .` и `git commit --amend` и что? Получается по вашим словам в этот момент будет создан еще один коммит? Так как содержимое отличается, верно? Но почему тогда я сто раз пользовался `git --amend`  и не создавались новые коммиты, а тут вдруг создались?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko если на коммит не ссылаются никакие ветки и метки, в т. ч. косвенно, коммит считается потеряшкой (dangling, [вот ещё пример про это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/505118/181100)) и не показывается никакими визуализаторами. Заметьте, что на графе коммитов верхушки у вас всегда чем-то отмечены. Потеряшку можно найти только если глубоко внутри, вроде журнала `git reflog`, если его ещё не успел стереть `git gc`. Так что новые коммиты ещё как создавались, только вы этого не замечали. На досуге сравните SHA текущего коммита до и после аменда.

Comment: Я так и не понял, почему какие-то коммиты после `git --amend` выглядят нормально и находятся в цепочке, а какие то вываливаются отдельными? И еще вы написали, что никогда не делать аменд на опубликованных комитах , что значит опубликованый коммит?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko старый коммит теряется всегда, если только он не достижим откуда-то ещё. Из ветки или метки. "Опубликованный коммит" это коммит, который кроме вас может быть у кого-то ещё, и этот кто-то может им пользоваться (готовить новый коммит поверх него, например). Если он внезапно исчезнет из репозитория (после amend & force-push), у него и у вас ветки разойдутся. Если при этом сделать их слияние, ситуация станет ещё смешнее, в истории будет два почти одинаковых коммита, до и после аменда. И почти наверняка будут конфликты.

Answer (score 9):

Коммит — неизменяемый (иммутабельный) объект. Поэтому все операции, которые «редактируют» и «перемещают» коммиты, на самом деле создают новые — но очень похожие на прежние.

## Из чего же сделаны наши коммиты

## В теории

Давайте посмотрим на коммит подробнее. 
В каждом коммите сохраняются следующие данные:

- Ссылка на содержимое рабочей области, которое сохранено в этом коммите. Само содержимое кодируется в другом объекте, а в коммите — только ссылка на объект.
- Ссылка на родительский (предыдущий) коммит. У первого коммита в репозитории родителя нет, у мерж-коммитов — два и более родителя.
- Автор изменений и дата сохранения изменений.
- Автор коммита и дата сохранения коммита. Может отличаться от автора изменений, когда сделанный одним человеком коммит другой человек  `rebase`.
- Сообщение — текстовый комментарий.

### На практике

Посмотреть на содержимое коммита можно с помощью команды `git cat-file commit <ссылка>`. В этом примере `# комментарии` добавлены мной, а остальное — вывод команды.

```
git cat-file commit HEAD

# ссылка на объект типа tree с данными о содержимом рабочей области
tree 9d548a63a91afe7da570cd7190888b7c59f1fc4f

# два родительских коммита — значит это мерж-коммит
parent a997a26aec530f536bc5949e4b316d685984dcd5
parent b6c26749463bf0c845637b127484ff6420b0148d

# автор, <почта автора>, UNIX timestamp, часовой пояс
author Nick Volynkin <email@server.tld> 1431889003 +0600
committer Nick Volynkin <email@server.tld> 1431889003 +0600

# сообщение
Merge branch 'newversion'
```

Всё содержимое коммита «запечатывается» с помощью хеш-функции SHA1. Значение этой функции служит в качестве идентификатора коммита. Если меняется хоть что-то, то значение хеш-функции будет совершенно другим.

## Что делают команды вроде `commit --amend` и `rebase`

Эти команды создают новые коммиты, но максимально переиспользуют содержимое предыдущих.

Например, с помощью `git commit --amend` мы можем поменять содержимое, сообщение, автора последнего коммита. Committer и дата поменяются автоматически на взятые из настроек `user.name <user.email>` и текущее время. Поскольку содержимое поменялось, поменялся и хеш — значит сохранить это содержимое на месте предыдущего коммита нельзя — нужно создавать новый.

Comment: Не совсем понял, значит представим ситуацию я сделал коммит "version1" и тут вспомнил, что мне нужно немного там что то сделать(поменять пару строк кода) , я поменял и вот теперь мне все нравится. Что я делаю я пишу `git add .` и `git commit --amend` и что? Получается по вашим словам в этот момент будет создан еще один коммит? Так как содержимое отличается, верно? Но почему тогда я сто раз пользовался `git --amend`  и не создавались новые коммиты, а тут вдруг создались?