# Как сделать другой репозиторий ответвлением в текущем?

Tags: git

[image: GIT. Как сделать другой репозиторий ответвлением в текущем?]

Как сделать другой репозиторий ответвлением в текущем?

Comment: то есть, формально, Вы хотите сделать rebase одного репозитория в другой?

Comment: А где именно вы будете это делать? в IDE или в приложении ГИТа, или на сайте?.

Comment: @KoVadim, с чего вы решили, что это rebase?

Comment: коммит А меняет свою "базу", поэтому, формально, это ребейз

Comment: А вам обязательно надо, чтобы эти ветки были связаны? Или вам будет достаточно, если эти ветки будут лежать "как есть" в одном репозитории на сервере, совершенно несвязанные между собой?

Comment: @0andriy это стоит опубликовать как ответ. )

Comment: @akp да, при `merge` в «буквенной» ветке появится новый коммит, соединяющий ее с «циферной» веткой. Но смысл-то сохранился: теперь в этой ветке есть нужные файлы, можно продолжать разработку. Ещё преимущество — не переписывались коммиты А—Г.

Comment: @akp а в вашей постановке задача не выполнима на 100%: нельзя чтобы у коммита появился предок и поменялось содержимое, но коммит остался тем же самым. Это будет совсем новый коммит, от старого можно разве что комментарий сохранить.

Comment: @akp дело не в конфликтах. Коммит — это грубо говоря текстовый файл, в котором построчно записаны автор, время создания, *ссылка на список файлов* и **ссылка на родительский коммит**. От этого файла считается хеш и этот хеш — идентификатор коммита. Если поменять родителя, то поменяется содержимое и хеш ну никак не может быть другим. Поэтому [Git создаёт новый коммит с новым хешем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662457/181472). То же самое с файлами: там же добавятся новые файлы, значит будет новый список файлов, значит изменится ссылка на список. Тоже хеш меняется.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Для начала, надо куда-то стащить коммиты из двух репозиториев сразу, ведь вы хотите получить комбинацию двух историй. Следуя вашим рисункам, работать будем в репозитории с коммитами-цифрами, а второй подключим к нему:

- Добавить в него репозиторий с коммитами-буквами как "удалённый источник" (remote) под названием `letters` (сами можете выбрать и другое, не принципиально):

  ```
  git remote add letters путь/к/другому/репозиторию
  ```
- Стащить оттуда коммиты/ветки/теги/всёподряд:

  ```
  git fetch letters
  ```
- Сделать и перейти в новую ветку `base`, начинающуюся с `master` ветки второго репозитория:

  ```
  git checkout -b base letters/master # Ветки ж master в обеих?
  ```
- Откройте журнал ветки `master` *текущего* репозитория и найдите коммит, от которого планируете ответвиться:

  ```
  git log master
  ```

  Скажем, пусть его хэш будет начинаться на `abcdef`.
- **Это всё были приготовления. А теперь заклинание:**

  ```
  git rebase --root --onto abcdef
  ```

  - Перевесить цепочку коммитов (`rebase`)...
  - ...от текущего до основания (`--root`)...
  - ...на коммит с хэшем `abcdef` (`--onto abcdef`).

В итоге имеем:

```
[1 ]---[2 ]---[3 ]---[4 ]---[5 ]  (master)
           \
            \
             \[А']---[Б']---[В']---[Г'] (base)
```

Всё как на рисунке. Кроме... хэшей буквенных коммитов. Изменение того, от чего они ответвлены, меняет и их хэши. Поэтому они и отмечены штрихами, т. к. это не на все 100% исходные коммиты. В них будет всё то же самое, кроме предков (если вы с конфликтами не столкнётесь).

---

*PS: мне решительно непонятно, для чего эти две истории нужно сцеплять у основания, хотя вам виднее, наверное. Git нормально обращается с несвязанными между собой ветками в одном репозитории.*

*Когда на гитхабе был биллинг по количеству закрытых репозиториев, некоторые экономили, собирая в одном репозитории ветки нескольких проектов. И это работало. Причём для тех, кому нужно было несколько проектов сразу, с помощью свежего Git (2.5+?) можно было держать несколько рабочих копий, относящихся к разным веткам одного репозитория, с помощью `git worktree add`. Такие дела.*

Comment: @akp вы сейчас решительно ничего не объяснили :)

Comment: @akp ветка в `Git` полностью определяется названием и **единственным** коммитом-верхушкой. Все коммиты, которые из него достижимы движением в сторону предков, попадут в историю.

Comment: @akp конечно же, история коммитов на удаленном репозитории не поменялась, и пока вы его не удалили, вы эту историю видите.

Comment: @D-side (режим зануды) «Изменение того, от чего они ответвлены» — не только родитель, ещё и содержимое поменялось существенно. В коммитах же не диффы/патчи хранятся, а ссылка на конкретное дерево проекта. И вот уже даже корневое дерево будет другим.

Comment: @akp а что вы понимаете под «параллельными» ветками?

Comment: @akp все ветки, что вы хотите присоединить к перенесённой истории, тоже придётся ребейзить. В ответе описан перенос только одной ветки. Но это уже классический ребейз будет.

Comment: @akp если у вас стотыщмильёнов веток, самое время избавиться от тех, что вам уже давно не нужны. Те, которыми пользуетесь, перенесите перед началом работы над ними, а остальные оставьте в покое. Их история будет по-прежнему доступна, если нужно (если не удалять ремоут второго репозитория, как я и поступил).

Comment: @akp да, и вы можете это даже проверить, сравнив содержимое `.git/refs/remotes/ремоут` в новом и `.git/refs/heads` в старом. Я потому и ставил под сомнение затею с соединением истории. Это осложняет переезд, а пользы от этого мало. Если с какого-то момента вам надо держать их содержимое в одной папке, есть обычный мердж.

Comment: @D-side, в Git возможны три типа объектов (если ничего кардинально не поменялось), один из них может вообще не содержать *комита-верхушки* (если я правильно понял, что вы под этим подразумеваете).

Comment: Поправлюсь — четыре.

Answer (score 5):

(Выношу из комментариев)

В вашем варианте, как правильно заметил [Nick Volynkin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin), решения быть не может. Надо выбрать либо **а)** общую базу, тогда изменения *А-Г* перейдут соответственно в *А'-Г'*, либо **б)** сохранение изменений, тогда ветка будет соединена как вы сами заметили "сверху".

Я выбрал приоритетом вариант **б)** и вот почему:

- изменения остаются неизменными;
- вы можете продолжать развитие старого проекта и "подливать", если нужно, в новый;
- `rebase`, так для краткости назовём вариант **а)**, вообще плохая практика для опубликованных репозиториев (тут уж от вас зависит строгость этого термина).

Теперь к сути. Вариант **б)** или `merge` делается в три команды:

```
git checkout -b <имя новой ветки> <хеш комита №2>
git fetch <URL репозитория №2> <имя ветки в репозитории №2>
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories FETCH_HEAD
```

Перед выполнением необходимо убедиться, что вы находитесь в нужной ветке репозитория №1.

В третьей строке специальная опция, чтобы избежать ошибки: *fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories*, о которой подробнее описано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories).

При наличии конфликтов на третьем этапе их надо разрешить самому так, как вы считаете нужным.

Результатом будет ветка `<имя новой ветки>` в репозитории №1.

Comment: У меня [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708667/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bc#comment1064108_708667) не хватает на целый ответ — можно я его к вам добавлю?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Добавьте, чтобы было видно, что это от вас.

Answer (score 3):

решений, конечно, много. например, можно воспользоваться командой *format-patch* и парной для неё *am*.

пример.

в каталоге `0` у нас хранилище с такой историей:

```
$ git log --one-line
a3d5387 5
2b7f19f 4
e1d8018 3
3e1fa25 2
7e8bd8d 1
```

а в каталоге `1` — с такой:

```
$ git log --one-line
5ea5e2c d
d42991a c
f980223 b
cff9df9 a
```

и хотим мы, чтобы коммиты `a b c d` из второго хранилища «приложились» к коммиту `2` из первого хранилища.

во-первых, надо получить все коммиты в виде patch-файла:

```
$ cd /путь/к/хранилищу/1
$ git format-patch --stdout --root cff9df9 > patch
$ git format-patch --stdout cff9df9..HEAD >> patch
```

две команды требуются для того, чтобы в файл `patch` попал и «корневой» коммит `a`

во-вторых, применить их с помощью команды `am` в хранилище `0`, предварительно создав там новую ветку, ответвлённую от коммита `2`:

```
$ cd /путь/к/хранилищу/0
$ git checkout -b new 3e1fa25
$ git am /путь/к/хранилищу/1/patch
Applying: a
Applying: b
Applying: c
Applying: d
```

если конфликтов не возникло, в хранилище `0` будет такая картина:

```
$ git log --oneline --all --decorate --graph 
* 20b6b2f (HEAD -> new) d
* 8dedddf c
* 6ddec5e b
* cb7a798 a
| * a3d5387 (master) 5
| * 2b7f19f 4
| * e1d8018 3
|/  
* 3e1fa25 2
* 7e8bd8d 1
```

хэш-суммы, понятно, стали у «приложенных» коммитов другие, но всё остальное — содержимое, дата, автор — на месте.

Comment: Это выглядит о-очень сложно.

Comment: @0andriy, напишите ответ проще.

Comment: А почему не rebase?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а с каких пор для полной формы rebase нужна общая база?

Comment: @apk, создать новый указатель типа «ветка» с названием «new» и установить его на коммит, хэш которого начинается с «3e1fa25»

Comment: @akp, понимаете, здесь не форум и не служба техподдержки. появляется у вас новый вопрос — его надо задавать не автору ответа на какой-то совсем другой вопрос, а с помощью кнопки задать вопрос в правом верхнем углу страницы.