# Merge или Rebase в GIT

Tags: git

Как известно в GIT существует два основных способа объединить изменения из двух разных веток:

1. Слияние (Merge);
2. Перемещение комитов (Rebase).

Вопрос: зачем перемещать комиты (Rebase), когда есть операция Merge, которая приводит к тому же результату? Или я что-то не правильно понимаю?

Comment: Угу. Не то, чтобы неправильно, скорее не смогли представить себе use case. Сейчас попробую найти мой ответ на один вопрос, который немного прояснит это.

Comment: Когда `merge` -- хорошо: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708667/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC/709249#709249

Comment: Как пользоваться `rebase` и когда: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/git-rebase-and-the-golden-rule-explained-70715eccc372

Comment: И просто как пример из жизни, в ежедневной практике я использую `rebase` примерно в 100 раз чаще, да, я не ошибся, чем `merge`. И причина тут очень проста — я не главный maintainer проекта, над которым я в основном работаю.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/179123/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Результат операций `merge` и `rebase` - разный. И я говорю не о состоянии файлов в последнем коммите, а об истории в репозитории.

`merge` порождает новый коммит-слияние, в то время как `rebase` изменяет сам переносимый коммит. Если точнее, то создается дубликат с такими же свойствами. Изменить коммит нельзя. Но если кроме переносимой ветки на коммит никто не ссылался, то он удаляется, и это выглядит как изменение.

Преимущество `merge` перед `rebase` в том, что легко отделить изменения по задаче, от изменений в процессе слияния. Но недостаток в том, что захламляется история.

Важность этих различий получается понять, когда нужно по относительно давней истории (т.е. от, что программисты сами уже не помнят) понять кто и главное зачем сделал конкретное изменение. Например, при помощи `blame` или `bisect`

Если над проектом я работаю один, и изменения достаточно просты - однозначно делаю `rebase`

Если изменения серьезные и гарантированны конфликты, то однозначно `merge`.

А вот если разработчиков несколько, но изменения просты, то тут нужно выбрать стратегию, удобную для всей команды.