# В чем разница между git rebase и git merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какая существенная разница между merge и rebase. Почитала ответ [по этой ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/942700/merge-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-rebase-%D0%B2-git) и единственное, что поняла - это то, что rebase может менять(меняет коммит), а merge создает новый, поэтому при просмотре истории более достоверная информация будет, если выполнять git merge. Тогда зачем вообще есть такая команда, как git rebase. Также при упоминании rebase, всегда упоминается линейность истории, так вот а что происходит при merge?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**merge** создаёт коммит слияния. И после **merge** остаются три удобных коммита. Чтобы продолжить используя только первую нить, только вторую нить, или все вместе.

```
коммит A ->
           |-> merge коммит C
коммит B ->
```

По сути **merge** создаёт историю.

А **rebase** меняет свою историю. Допустим вы написали свою `работа D` используя только видимую ветку `коммит A`.

```
         > работа D 
        /
коммит A ->
           |-> merge коммит C
коммит B ->
```

но передумали и перенесли всю свою работу в появившуюся ветку `коммит B`. И сделали **rebase** на коммит B :

```
коммит A ->
           |-> merge коммит C
коммит B ->
        \
         > работа D
```

или после **rebase** на коммит С :

```
коммит A ->
           |-> merge коммит C -> работа D
коммит B ->
```

**rebase** используют если хотят продолжить работу основываясь от чьей-то работы другого человека. Все коммиты вашей ветки `работа D` это новые коммиты, всё переписывается по-новой и забывается всё старое.

Линейность это то, что ваша `работа D` использует всё, что видно (A,B,C). Если использовать **merge** вместо **rebase** получится такой граф :

```
         > работа D             -> \
        /                           |-> merge D & C
коммит A ->                        / 
           |-> merge коммит C   -> 
коммит B ->
```

И есть возможность продолжать вашу ветку как без слияния так и с ним. **rebase** имеет разрушительное действие для истории. Если вы передумали пользоваться коммитом C то прийдется опять делать **rebase**.

Comment: То есть получается при merge просто добавляются новые коммиты, а при rebase эти коммиты объединяются(и в истории получается не несколько, а всего один коммит)?

Comment: Эти команды с полностью разным действием. Если переехали с `ветки A` на `ветку B` то в вашей ветке исчезнет все изменения ветки `коммит A` но появятся изменения ветки `коммит B`. Все коммиты новой ветки `работа D` переписываются по-новой.

Answer (score 3):

rebase нужен для порядка (линейность истории), чтоб потом смотреть и понимать.
rebase переносит коммиты поверх того, что было в результирующей ветке.
merge оставляет коммиты, как есть, просто добавляя связующий коммит между ветками.

Тут целая книга:
https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2

Answer (score 1):

**merge** - оставляет историю (больше коммитов, после merge - новый коммит слияния в основной ветке, другая продолжает существовать и не зависит от основной)

**rebase** - переписывает историю (меньше коммитов, после rebase последний коммит перезаписывается и остаётся основным. Ветка, которая была родительской - удаляется).

Answer (score 0):

**merge** добавляет коммит мержа и сохраняет историю коммитов
**rebase** применяет все коммиты на целевую ветку и удаляет историю коммитов

Comment: `удаляет историю коммитов` — расшифруйте, что именно вы имеете в виду (прямо в тексте ответа, нажав [edit]). потому как без расшифровки это звучит несколько странно.