# Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно обновить локальную ветку git

Tags: git

Всем привет! Работаю в локальной ветке (например branch1) созданной от develop, за некоторое время в удаленной ветке develop произошли изменения, теперь чтобы обновить свою локальную ветку branch1, я сначала обновляю локальный develop, дальше делаю checkout на branch1, потом встаю на ветке develop и в меню есть 2 варианта:

1. Rebase 'branch1' onto 'develop'
2. Merge 'develop' into 'branch1'

Не понимаю, что тут правильнее выбрать вроде по логике если мне нужно из develop обновить branch1 то это 2-й вариант.

Comment: Из [ask] - **Кратко опишите вашу конкретную проблему в заголовке**

Comment: делайте merge, а не rebase

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [В чем разница между git rebase и git merge?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1174810/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-git-rebase-%d0%b8-git-merge)

Comment: делайте rebase, а не merge

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Надо перейти на `branch1` и запустить команду.

```
git rebase origin develop
```

Если будут конфликты, то решите конфликты (например в `IDE PhpStorm`).

Дальше запуск сразу двух команд.

```
git add . && git rebase --continue.
```

И переделать последние 2 действия если дальше будут конфликты.

После этого локальная ветка полностю обновиться.

Другой вариант `git merge origin develop`.
Опять же если будут конфликты нужно их решить.
Потом сделать `commit`.

**git merge(слияние)**

Слияние принимает содержимое другой ветки и объединяет их с целевой веткой. В этом процессе изменяется только целевая ветка. История исходных веток остается неизменной.

Минус в том что история коммитов может быть заполнена множеством коммитов.

**git rebase**

Rebase сжимает все изменения в один. Затем он интегрирует это в целевую ветку.

В отличие от merge, rebase перезаписывает историю, потому что она передает завершенную работу из одной ветки в другую. И устраняется нежелательная история.

Comment: Ответ основан на личном мнении, минусую.  На вопрос "что делать: merge или rebase" нужно дать ответ, содержащий хоть какое-то объяснение причин такого выбора

Comment: *"Rebase сжимает все изменения в один."* - вообще-то нет, сжимает squash, это отдельная операция. И историю он не перезаписывает, и ничего не передает между ветками, и не устраняет, и принудительный пуш не нужен.