# Git rebase, Current branch is up to date

Tags: git, git-rebase

Добрый день, не получается заребейсить:

```
git shrebase master lalala
```

Пишет:

```
Current branch lalala is up to date.
```

Но в ветви lalala есть последний коммит, которого нет в master.

Прошу помощи разобраться.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Почему ничего не происходит?

Команда `rebase` как бы переставляет *текущую* ветку на целевую, а точнее на ее последний коммит.

Поскольку последний коммит `master` уже есть в ветке `lalala`, то переставлять некуда — в этом смысле ветка `lalala` актуальна, "up to date".

```
A - B - C   (master)
         \
          D (lalala)
```

#### Как перенести нужный коммит в `master`?

Если вы хотите, чтобы коммит из `lalala` попал в `master`, то нужно работать не с `lalala`, а с `master`. Проще всего переключиться туда и замержить ветку с нужным коммитом:

```
git checkout master
git merge lalala
```

Результат:

```
A - B - C - D  (master, lalala)
```

#### Когда `rebase` все-таки будет переставлять ветку `lalala`?

Когда головной коммит ветки `master` не принадлежит ветке `lalala`. Например:

```
# было:
A - B - C - X  (master)
         \
          D - E (lalala)

$ git checkout lalala
$ git rebase master

# стало:
A - B - C - X  (master)
             \
              D' - E'  (lalala)
```

В результате вся ветка будет «переставлена» на коммит `X`. Каждый из коммитов этой ветки, которого нет в `master`, будет [пересоздан](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662457/181472):

- новым предком `D` является `X`, а не `C` — появляется коммит `D'`
- новым предком `E` является `D'`, а не `D` – появляется коммит `E'`