# Как удалить ссылку на коммит из Issue? | Коммит не видно через git log

Tags: git, github

Есть репозиторий: https://github.com/w3lifer/yii2-i18n-js.

Нужно было сделать `amend` сообщения последнего коммита, чтобы тот ссылался на соответствующее Issue:

```
git commit -m 'closes #1: ...' --amend
git push -f
git tag -d 2.1.1
git push origin :refs/tags/2.1.1
git tag 2.1.1
git push --tags
```

Соответственно, автоматически закрылся `Issue #1`; но как оказалось, я ошибся в номере — нужно было указать номер `#2`. Тогда я повторил процедуру, но уже с верным номером:

```
git commit -m 'closes #2: ...' --amend
git push -f
git tag -d 2.1.1
git push origin :refs/tags/2.1.1
git tag 2.1.1
git push --tags
```

Я ожидал, что ссылка в `Issue #1` исчезнет и он откроется автоматически, но этого не произошло: [там](https://github.com/w3lifer/yii2-i18n-js/issues/1) она осталась и указывает на коммит [closes #1: ...](https://github.com/w3lifer/yii2-i18n-js/commit/2c4b2a932d1f9ae8a7423d1c49514069b3338c67).

Из всего этого у меня возникло несколько вопросов.

1. <s>Разве коммит `closes #1: ...` не должен был исчезнуть?</s>
2. <s>Почему его нигде не видно: ни в `git log`, ни через `gitk`, ни через IDE, однако можно сделать его `checkout`?</s>
3. Как его можно удалить из `Issue #1`?

---

Насчёт третьего вопроса: пробовал, если просто сослаться на Issue без [ключевых слов](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-using-keywords) для закрытия, а потом удалить ссылку из сообщения, то в Issue ссылка исчезает.

---

- https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1081
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/21983964/4223982

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему \`git commit --amend\` создает новый коммит?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/662457/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-git-commit-amend-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82)

Comment: Переписанные коммиты видны в `git reflog`

Answer (score 3):

Git не удаляет коммиты и не перезаписывает их. Когда пользователь делает `git commit --amend`, создается новый коммит, а старый становится невидим, если не привязать его к какой-нибудь ветке.

Если вы знаете хэш коммита, то на него можно переключиться командой `git checkout 5ccd263b4` (где 5ccd263b4 - ваш хэш).

Гитхаб адресует коммиты по хэшу (это хорошо заметно в ссылке, что вы предоставили), потому и отображает ссылку корректно.

Плюс к сказанному: у гитхаба скорее всего нет никакой процедуры отслеживания переписывания истории, т.к. сам факт переписывания истории в публичном репозитории является плохой практикой.